# How to render two html pages in one windows using electron.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm new to **electron.js**.  I was trying to create a window, which has a default side bar / page, and im trying to view separate windows when clicking the left side buttons. I searched a lot, but only thing that i found is how to create multiple windows.

**IMAGE :**

[image]

**CODE**

```js
app.on('ready', function () {
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    // Load html in window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        // pathname: path.join(__dirname, './layouts/settings.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: false
    }));

    // // Quit app when closed
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        app.quit();
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Shop Flow Sync Tool</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin-top:15px" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="#" id="menu-btn-settings" role="button">Settings</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="#" id="menu-btn-health" role="button">aaa</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="#" id="menu-btn-sync-now" role="button">bbb</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="#" id="menu-btn-sync-user" role="button">ccc</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block" href="#" id="menu-btn-about" role="button">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div id="alert-msg"></div>
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./assets/js/jquery.min.js');</script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.helpers.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: one browserWindow can just only render one html file. Please think as this is the chromium browser without toolbar

Comment: So, if you want to render 2 html files. You should create new BrowserWindow

Comment: But you can achieve your goal using BrowserView
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view